# Html5 send e mail form

Tags: html, email

I have a website but I can't provide send e-mail form template.

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-top-right">
    <div class="contact-textarea">
        <form>
            <input type="text" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}"/>
            <input type="text" value="Second Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Second Name';}"/>
            <input type="text" value="Email Id" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email Id';}"/>
            <textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message..</textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
            <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" >
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where do I put my e-mail address?

Comment: Don't get this wrong, but this reads as if you have no idea what you are doing. A real answer to this would take several pages of text to explain. That is not the idea behind this place. I suggest that instead you read a few beginners tutorials and work through a few examples to understand the basics of how web programming works.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`mailto`** in **`form's action`** tag like below:

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-top-right">
  <div class="contact-textarea">
      <form method="GET" action="mailto:test@example.com" enctype="text/plain">
         <input type="text" value="First Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name';}"/>
         <input type="text" value="Second Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Second Name';}"/>
         <input type="text" value="Email Id" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email Id';}"/>
         <textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message..</textarea>
         <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
         <input type="reset" value="CLEAR" >
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```